# Why am I getting strange garbage with NSInteger and arc4random?

Tags: objective-c, random, nsinteger, arc4random

I'm trying to get a random number using arc4random between -60 and 60. I generate avnumber between 1 and 120 inclusively, and then subtract 60.

If this is in one line, I get weird results whenever the number is negative.

```
//Loop illustrates point better.
while (1) {
    //Gets garbage numbers approximately half the time (when random1 should be negative)
    NSInteger random1 = 1 + (arc4random() %120) - 60;
    NSLog (@"random1: %li", random1);

    //Essentially same thing, but works fine.
    NSInteger random2 = 1 + (arc4random() %120);
    NSInteger random3 = random2 - 60;
    NSLog (@"random2: %li random3: %li", random2, random3);
}
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arc4random()` returns an unsigned integer, `1 + (arc4random() %120) - 60;` is interpreted as unsigned, then assigned to `NSInteger random1`.

You can either cast the return value of `(arc4random() %120)` to a signed integer:

```
NSInteger random1 = 1 + (NSInteger)(arc4random() %120) - 60;
```

or store the intermediate result of `arc4random()` in an unsigned integer:

```
NSInteger r = (arc4random() %120);
NSInteger random1 = 1 + r - 60;
```

Also note that the arc4random man page recommends using `arc4random_uniform()` over modulo constructs:

> arc4random_uniform() is recommended over constructions like ``arc4random() % upper_bound'' as it avoids
>        "modulo bias" when the upper bound is not a power of two.

Comment: A typo. Should be `arc4random_uniform`, which generates random integers in a range with a uniform distribution.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect the problem stems from the fact that `arc4random` is returning a `u_int32_t` (an unsigned 32-bit integer) between 0 and (2**32)-1, but doing a calculation only appropriate for signed integers.

Regardless, when generating random numbers, it's better to use `arc4random_uniform`, which avoids the modulo bias of your code. This bias will be barely observable, but nonetheless, you should use:

```
NSInteger random = 1 + (NSInteger)arc4random_uniform(120) - 60;
```

Or, technically, if you want numbers between -60 and 60 inclusively, you should use:

```
NSInteger random = (NSInteger)arc4random_uniform(121) - 60;
```

Comment: Upon trial, I must un-accept your answer. While it definitely is helpful to know about that, @Sebastian's has a solution while yours doesn't.

Comment: @jazz14456 That's fine. Do the cast if you must (like I have in my revised answer). But do not use `arc4random`. Use `arc4random_uniform`. Or, if you really want to use the `%` syntax and the bias that entails and want values between -60 and 60 (inclusive), then use 121 (e.g. `(NSInteger)arc4random() % 121 - 60`).

Comment: There is no good to reason to use arc4random for similar situations(I think) to all people who are experiencing this problem.

Answer (score 0):

For starters `arc4random()` returns an `u_int32_t`, unsigned 32 bit number. Unsigned numbers can not be negative so subtracting a number larger then the unsigned value results in unspecified behavior.

In the second case you assign the mod'ed value to a signed integer that can have a negative number.

As @Rob states in his answer, use `arc4random_uniform` instead of mod'ing to get a range in order to eliminate bias.

Comment: AFAIK the overflow behaviour of *unsigned* integers is well defined in c. Does objective-c differ from c here?

Comment: Objective-C is of course "C", it is a strict superset. Yes, it is well defined but at least in this case incorrect and confusing. Consider how one represents a negative number with an unsigned integer in a meaningful way.